# Firebase: Why is my set (with merge : true) operation removes all other fields in my document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Assume a document on Firebase Firestore representing a house

```
{
  id: "1234",
  owner: "John",
  address: "123 Something Ave.",
  residents: [],
}
```

I have a cloud function that is supposed to add residents to the house.
Also note: the residents field isn't always there from the start. Idea is to add it when the first resident is added.

This is my operation, which is part of a cloud function:

```
db.collection("houses")
      .doc(house_id)
      .set(
        {
          residents: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
            uid: context.auth.uid,
            first_name: driverData.first_name,
            last_name: driverData.last_name,
          }),
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
```

But instead of creating this field with the array an leaving all the other data in the document, the function completely removes all the other data and I am only left with the residents array field.

Why is that?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Are you sure you don't have any other code also modifying the document?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not sure what I've changed as I tried it like 5 times, but it is working now. Will delete this question in a few minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the difference:

- `set` with `merge` will update fields in the document or create it if it doesn't exists

`update` will update fields but will fail if the document doesn't exist

To update just the `residents` field, you can use the `update()` method instead of `set()` method.

```js
db.collection("houses")
  .doc(house_id)
  .update({
    residents: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
      uid: context.auth.uid,
      first_name: driverData.first_name,
      last_name: driverData.last_name,
    }),
  });
```